# create a viewcontroller below other viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller

I want to create an ios app in which I want to flip `uiviewcontrollers`. I want to use swipe gesture to change between `uiviewcontrollers`.

I have 2 `uiviewcontrollers`, in which I want to set one view controller to the top of `uiviewcontroller` cover and one view controller to the bottom ,and then make an animation that let a top `uiviewcontroller` slide to left to out of screen and the bottom `uiviewcontroller` will appear step by step.

What is the Best way to do this ?

Comment: why not use UIView instand of UIViewController

Comment: my project now is a big project, and i must continue with the old code, so it become a big problem

Answer (score 3):

- Create a RootViewController with container views.
- Add the child view controllers to the root view controller.
- Add gesture recognizers to manipulate the views.
- Use the "view controller containement" a feature of iOS5, to make managing the lifecycle calls easier.

Comment: i am only beginner with ios, i have ever created this animation for 2 view in a viewcontroller, but now i want change all viewcontroller. the problem is how to show 2 viewcontroller (top and botom) not 2 view

Comment: Yes, if you have have a Root or master view controller, you can add child view controllers. Some of these view controllers may have their views appear in the current window. You can layer, use gestures, animation,etc Take a look at view controller containement in the API docs.

Comment: @Makio first of all learn a [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). You cannot SHOW a Controller, you can show your view (as a subclass of UIView).

Comment: i have 2 viewcontroller, i will add top viewcontroller as child view controller of botom viewcontroller, and view of botom viewcontroller as a subview of view of top viewcontroller, if do that, when i move the view of top viewcontroller ----> the view of botom viewcontroller move too, is that ?

Comment: @OdNairy i know that, i write show controller that i mean show the view of viewcontroller

Comment: I think no. But i hadn't practice with new container-way style. 
As I see the new way: you have a root controller and child controller. You detect a swipe gesture and perform `transitionWithView…` with your root and child controllers

Comment: Michael's is better because he linked to an example (I had a quick look, but couldn't find a good one). . . If you found one of the answers helpful, please accept it.

Comment: i found a way to do this, i test it and it run ok, but i think have some problem in this way.... i use a super view, the view of controler view is child of this view, and i swipe the child view and the super view is fix, but like i do that,i can run ok but i think some problem around push controller, it right ?

Comment: This is the right approach. Take a look at didMoveToParentViewController, etc methods. These trigger lifecycle calls. When you add the VC to a parent, you should call these methods, rather than calling the lifecycle methods directly.

Answer (score 1):

As Jasper wrote you should create new `UIViewController` - "root" which will hold the child `UIViewControllers`- "bottom" and "top". It will also display their views. To achieve an effect that "bottom" is underneath, you should add its view as a subview first.

Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html It might give you an idea how to handle with child `UIViewControllers`